# Как вернуть массив объектов, содержащий только определенные задачи? Применение .filter()

Tags: javascript

Имеется заготовка класса Todos:

```
export default class Todos {
  // В данном случае конструктор не принимает никаких параметров,
  // а только задает массив объектов — пунктов для списка задач

  constructor() {
    this.todos = [
      {
        title: "Изучить Классы JS",
        category: "работа"
      },
      {
        title: "Не забыть покушать",
        category: "личное"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Функция getWork() должна возвращать  массив объектов, содержащий только рабочие задачи. Попробовал вариант с:

```
 getWork() {
return this.todos.filter(category => category === "работа")
  }
```

Результат выдает как undefined. В чем может быть проблема? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Надо так:

```
return this.todos.filter(el => el.category === "работа")
```

Потому что в аргумент приходит элемент массива, т.е. объект с `title` и `category`

Comment: Либо так: return this.todos.filter(({category}) => category === "работа")